# Shading (Stretching) artefact while baking

Tags: shaders, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake some textures for a model I am working on and I'm getting some weird stretching artefacts.
In the viewport, I don't see any stretching, but once I bake the textures, the stretching appears.
It's a table model with a mirror, bevel, and weighted normal modifiers applied to it.
The UV's are clean and optimized too. No stretching there

MODEL IN OBJECT MODE
[image]

MODEL IN RENDER MODE (VIEWPORT)
[image]

MODEL WITH BAKED TEXTURES
[image]

HOW THE NORMAL MAP LOOKS LIKE
[image]

HOW THE UV ISLANDS ARE LAYED OUT
[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you show the baked normal map? Also, try to select the problematic geometry in *Edit Mode*, and run *Mesh > Normals > Reset Vectors* or *Mesh > Normals > Smooth Vectors*. Let us know which improves the situation if any does.

Comment: Alright. Thanks; I'll try that.
In the meantime, I have updated the question to include the normal map and the UV layout. I'll try what you suggested and give feedback.

Comment: 5 minutes later...

OMG, it actually worked. Thanks a lot, Mr A
The Normals are now perfect. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the problematic geometry in *Edit Mode*, and run *Mesh > Normals > Reset Vectors* or *Mesh > Normals > Smooth Vectors*.